# AJAX file upload onchange as opposed to onsubmit

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, iframe, onsubmit

I am using the following code to effect an iframe that allows an ajax file upload on submit of the form without refresh.

This works as expected

```
window.onload=init; 
function init() {
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit=function() {
    document.getElementById('form').target = 'iframe'; 
            }
        }
```

What i would like to do is the same thing but '`onchange`' of the file field input, i.e. when the user has chosen a file, to autmatically trigger the `init()` function and thus upload the file. I have tried with this code:

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange=function(){...
```

This doesn't work, and i'm completely stuck. Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

    // add old fashioned but reliable event handler
    document.getElementById('file_input').onchange = function() {
        // submit the form that contains the target element
        this.form.submit();
    }
}

</script>

<iframe name="my_iframe"></iframe>

<form target="my_iframe"
      action="your/file.ext"
      method="post"
      enctype="multipart/formdata">

    <input type="file" name="my_file" id="file_input">

    <!-- for no js users -->
    <noscript>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit">
    </noscript>

</form>
```

Comment: The OP wasn't explicit about what doesn't work. The code above does work however.

Answer (score 0):

i think something like [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) will solve your issue hopefully, comment if you want more info on how to use it...

Comment: Sounds interesting but I'm not currently using jquery. are you aware of a way to get this working in vanilla javascript as jquery seems like overkill for this small feature.

Comment: nah not aware of a way around without jquery, sorry... you might want to google, "javascript onfileselect" or something

Answer (score 0):

Give the file input element an id and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(element).change(function(e){
    fileInfo = e.currentTarget.files[0];
    init();
  });
});
```